# rostopic list return topics, but not able to echo topic

Tags: ros, beagleboneblack, gpsd-client, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My configuration looks like:

Beaglebone black with GPS + laptop. Both running Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo.

I would like to run roscore at laptop and node gpsd_client at beaglebone.
I set following variables:
At laptop (ip 192.168.7.1):

```
export ROS_IP=192.168.7.1
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.7.1
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.7.1:11311
```

At beaglebone (ip 192.168.7.2):

```
export ROS_IP=192.168.7.2
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.7.1
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.7.1:11311
```

I'm able to ping each other.
I'm able to do rostopic list from both.
But I'm not able to do rostopic echo fix.

roswtf give following error msg:

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
ERROR: connection refused to [http://192.168.7.1:41219/]
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 3 error(s).

ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /gpsd_client

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /gpsd_client->/rosout (/rosout)

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/gpsd_client/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/gpsd_client/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://192.168.7.1:58483]
 * service [/gpsd_client/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/gpsd_client/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://192.168.7.1:58483]
```

I see error

```
ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /gpsd_client->/rosout (/rosout)
```

but unfortunately I don't now how should I fix it.

I tried another configuration, when roscore was running at beaglebone with gpsd_client, and do echo from laptop - this is working without any problem. Just problem apear when I run roscore at one machine and node in another.

I hope that my problem is trivial to fix and I'm just missing some setting.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216571/rostopic-list-return-topics,-but-not-able-to-echo-topic/) by [darkom](https://answers.ros.org/users/23688/darkom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> At laptop (ip 192.168.7.1):

> ```
> export ROS_IP=192.168.7.1
> ```

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.7.1
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.7.1:11311
```

> At beaglebone (ip 192.168.7.2):

> ```
> export ROS_IP=192.168.7.2
> ```

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.7.1
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.7.1:11311
```

Is that an actual copy/paste? Because you have `ROS_HOSTNAME` set to the same IP on both machines, which is not what you want I guess.

Also, you should not / don't need to set both `ROS_IP` and `ROS_HOSTNAME` at the same time. Just setting `ROS_IP` should be enough (but make sure to set it to the correct IP). From the [wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables - ROS_IP/ROS_HOSTNAME](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME) page:

> [..] The options are mutually exclusive, **if both are set `ROS_HOSTNAME` will take precedence**. Use `ROS_IP` if you are specifying an IP address, and `ROS_HOSTNAME` if you are specifying a host name. [..]

If you then have `ROS_HOSTNAME` set to an incorrect IP, things will probably not work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [darkom](https://answers.ros.org/users/23688/darkom/) on 2015-08-27**:
Thank you so much. Now it is working just great.